# Custom Text in Android TextView

Tags: android, string, android-studio, textview, string.xml

How to achieve TextView with text like below image:

[image]

Below solution provide me thoroug code.
[Subscript and Superscript a String in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543454/subscript-and-superscript-a-string-in-android)

**How to add String for above image in string.xml?**

Comment: I believe you want to create a custom textview then use it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726659/how-to-write-the-to-the-power-and-some-text-like-as-shown-in-java-or-android

Comment: I got my solution answer from @Nicolas Simon. Thanks to all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your string defined in strings.xml as follow :

```
<string name="fourth">4&lt;SUP&gt;&lt;/SUP&gt;</string>
```

And if you need to call it from code, use :

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.fourth)));
```

Comment: Thanks :) I got my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("4<sup>th</sup>"));
```