# How to type x^2 (subscript and superscript) in TextView

Tags: java, android

I am making a calculator app in Android Studio(Mac OS) in which I'm trying to include **square(x^2)** `Button`.
I've set my square as a TextView.

I've tried all the links mentioned but none worked for me to type it as in proper equation format.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/square"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="-5dp"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

I've also tried below code in `MainActivity.java` file:-

```
squareButton = findViewById(R.id.square);
squareButton.setText(Html.fromHtml("x<sup>2</sup>"));
```

Examples tried
[Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726659/how-to-write-the-to-the-power-and-some-text-like-as-shown-in-java-or-android) [Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156032/android-string-resource-superscript/22105902#22105902) Didn't work!

P.S. I've set `minSdkVersion 14`  and `targetSdkVersion 26`!

Comment: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                    {
                        description_tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("x<sup>2</sup>",Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
                    }

Comment: Try this lib it helped me displaying the Math functions in TextView https://github.com/kexanie/MathView

Comment: What do you see in you TextView after `setText`

Comment: @Jacky I'm Seeing Simply X2 in TextView

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subscript and Superscript a String in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543454/subscript-and-superscript-a-string-in-android)

Comment: Duplicate of a question but not the answer, because the way has been deprecated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Android has native support for sub/superscript type text know as [SubscriptSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/SubscriptSpan.html) and [SuperscriptSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/SuperscriptSpan.html)

**Sample Usage of Superscript (eg X^2)**

```
String text = "X2";
SuperscriptSpan superscriptSpan = new SuperscriptSpan();
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
builder.setSpan(
                superscriptSpan,
                text.indexOf("2"),
                text.indexOf("2") + String.valueOf("2").length(),
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

yourTextView.setText(builder);
```

I have found a really good [example](https://android--examples.blogspot.com/2016/08/android-subscript-and-superscript.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just do some short research, `Html.fromHtml` is deprecated in Android N+.

Correct way should be this:

```
strButton = Html.fromHtml(html,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
```

Just do a check like @Vishva Dave 's comment, for android versions:

```
String strButton;
String html = "x<sup>2</sup>";
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    strButton = Html.fromHtml(html,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
}
else{
    strButton = Html.fromHtml(html);
}

squareButton.setText(strButton);
```

Comment: Thanks, But It didn't Work, Still getting same X2